# How to create a block with CCK dropdown lists and some values in it?

Tags: 6, entities, nodes

As the question is clear, I want to create a block in the left sidebar and which contains sample values in it. How to do this? I am very new to Drupal

Answer (score 1):

This is something you can do in Drupal 7 easily as they now use enititys. However in Drupal 6 you will need to use a custom module like [Node Blocks](http://drupal.org/project/nodeblock)